# vim-coffee-script does not work

Tags: vim, coffeescript, vim-plugin

I installed coffeeScript and CoffeeLint in the following way:

```
# .bashrc
export NODE_MODULES=/home/uqmlore1/apps/node_modules

$ npm install --prefix /home/uqmlore1/apps/node_modules -g coffee-script
$ coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 1.6.3

$ npm install --prefix /home/uqmlore1/apps/node_modules -g coffeelint
$ coffeelint
bash: coffeelint: command not found
$ ls ~/apps/node_modules/lib/node_modules/coffeelint/bin
coffeelint
```

Than I installed [vim-coffee-script plugin](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script) with vundle. However I am not able to compile from Vim neither CoffeeLint works. This is [.vimrc](https://github.com/mictadlo/VimIDE/blob/master/.vimrc) which I used for CoffeeScript. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What you did wrong is asking here instead of the plugin's issue tracker. And, rather obviously, coffeelint is not installed, so if the installation procedure you followed is the recommended one, you must ask on coffeelint's issue tracker as well.

Comment: Thank you, I posted it here: https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script/issues/147 , https://github.com/clutchski/coffeelint/issues/170

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [manual](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script#coffee_linter) pays off:

```
let coffee_linter = '/home/uqmlore1/apps/node_modules/lib/node_modules/coffeelint/bin/coffeelint'
```

in your `.vimrc` might help.